# Is there a way to get index while iterating through a collection in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

The below example will generate a list of names of players, where players is a data set from a [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) database.

```
<template name="players">
  {{#each topScorers}}
    <div>{{name}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

However, I want to display four of them in a row, and after four players is printed, I want to divide the line by `<hr />` and then continue. For instance,

```
<template name="players">
  {{#each topScorers}}
    <div style="float:left;">{{name}}</div>
    {{if index%4==0}}
      <hr style="clear:both;" />
    {{/if}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

How can I do something like that while iterating through collections?

Answer (score 7):

Another solution, in line with maintaining the reactivity of the collection, is to use a template helper with the [map cursor function](http://docs.meteor.com/#map).

Here's an example showing how to return the index when using each with a collection:

```
index.html:

<template name="print_collection_indices">
  {{#each items}}
    index: {{ this.index }}
  {{/each}}
</template>

index.js:

Items = new Meteor.Collection('items');

Template.print_collection_indices.items = function() {
  var items = Items.find().map(function(doc, index, cursor) {
    var i = _.extend(doc, {index: index});
    return i;
  });
  return items;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no easy way to do this right now, the latest version of handlebars supports an `@index` field (which would do what you want), but it's not yet implemented in meteor's version - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/489.

Certainly you could implement your own `{{#each_with_index}}` helper, it would look something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_with_index', function(items, options) {
  var out = '';
  for(var i=0, l=items.length; i<l; i++) {
    var key = 'Branch-' + i;
    out = out + Spark.labelBranch(key,function(){ 
      options.fn({data: items[i], index: i});
    });
  }

  return out;
});
```

The downside of this is you lose the niceness of meteor's `{{#each}}` helper, which doesn't reactively re-render the whole list when a single item changes.

EDIT: thanks @zorlak for pointer to https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/281#issuecomment-13162687