# Using @index in meteor #each iterator doesn't work

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

why doesn't this work in meteor? https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/250

Comment: See a good answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329898/is-there-a-way-to-get-index-while-iterating-through-collection-in-meteor][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329898/is-there-a-way-to-get-index-while-iterating-through-collection-in-meteor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not yet implemented in meteor's version of handlebars; there's a subtlety about the reactivity of `@index` rendering properly. You can read more about it here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/489#issuecomment-11270564

Answer (score 9):

This is definitely a frustration for me as well. In the meantime I made a handlebars helper to parse anything into named 'key' and 'value' objects:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('key_value', function(context, options) {
  var result = [];
  _.each(context, function(value, key, list){
    result.push({key:key, value:value});
  })
  return result;
});
```

This would be used with the `#each` operator like:

```
<dl class="attributes">
  {{#each key_value attributes}}
    <dt>{{key}}</dt><dd>{{value}}</dd>
  {{/each}}
</dl>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I used this with a little modification. I simply add a `_key` field to the `value` and push `value` directly to the results.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get it to work is to use a standard Meteor template helper with the [map cursor function](http://docs.meteor.com/#map).

Here's an example showing how to return the index when using each with a collection:

```
index.html:

<template name="print_collection_indices">
  {{#each items}}
    index: {{ this.index }}
  {{/each}}

index.js:

Items = new Meteor.Collection('items');

Template.print_collection_indices.items = function() {
  var items = Items.find().map(function(doc, index, cursor) {
    var i = _.extend(doc, {index: index});
    return i;
  });
  return items;
};
```

Comment: The map() method returns an array instead of a cursor so you loose reactivity...