# Why Does Using {{@...}} In a Meteor Template Cause Errors?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

With a simple code of

```
{{#each array}}
{{@index}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

a flood of errors appears. Same happens with `{{@key}}` for objects. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source (at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/handlebars/parse.js): It doesn't look like the `{{@ ..}}` set of expressions are supported with the Handlebars version packaged with Meteor.

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely a frustration for me as well. In the meantime I made a handlebars helper to parse anything into named 'key' and 'value' objects:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('key_value', function(context, options) {
  var result = [];
  _.each(context, function(value, key, list){
    result.push({key:key, value:value});
  })
  return result;
});
```

This would be used with the `#each` operator like:

```
<dl class="attributes">
  {{#each key_value attributes}}
    <dt>{{key}}</dt><dd>{{value}}</dd>
  {{/each}}
</dl>
```

(I also just posted this to related [Using @index in meteor #each iterator doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430455/using-index-in-meteor-each-iterator-doesnt-work/19131152#19131152))

Comment: A more concise implementation would be to use `_.map` instead of `_.each`: `return _.map(context, function(value, key) { return {key: key, value: value}; });`

Comment: However note that your workaround significantly affects the rendering performance of an app. Whenever any single item is changed, every item will be re-rendered. This may be a problem for large collections.

Comment: Ah, yes – that's definitely a good point. I think Meteor will be addressing this in later versions. Their new UI demo described much better management of markup. Hopefully it will include the key/value type lists.