# How to get the index in meteor in each

Tags: meteor

How to get the each loop index in meteor.@index is not working.Please help me.

```
Template.apichange.helpers({
    api_rest_data: function () 
    {     
        return Session.get("api_rest_list");
    }
   });




 {{#each api_rest_data}}
                    <tr>
                        <td><select id="methodname"> <option id="optn" value="{{ method_name }}"> {{ @index }}  </option></select></td>

                    </tr>
   {{/each}}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430455/using-index-in-meteor-each-iterator-doesnt-work

Comment: possible duplicate of [In meteor is there a way to access array index in spacebars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815713/in-meteor-is-there-a-way-to-access-array-index-in-spacebars)

Answer (score 2):

It requires another helper, check out [my solution](https://github.com/meteorinaction/ch05-reactivevar/blob/master/house-sitter2/client/client.js#L126) that I have used in my book on Meteor:

```
Template.registerHelper('withIndex', function (list) {
    var withIndex = _.map(list, function (v, i) {
        v.index = i;
        return v;
    });
    return withIndex;
});
```

This registers a global helper named `withIndex`. Whenever you call it on an array that is used inside the `each` context it will allow you to use `{{index}}` in the same way you would have used `{{@index}}` to tell which position in the array each element has.

Adjust your inclusion tag to pass `api_rest_data` to `withIndex` first:

```
{{#each withIndex api_rest_data}}
```

Comment: I believe this should be `UI.registerHelper` instead of `Template.registerHelper`. Other wise, I think this is an elegant solution.

Comment: The `UI` namespace was deprecated in [0.9.4](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v094). [Template.registerHelper](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper) is now the correct function.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Stephan for this intermediate solution. Here is my version; it allows for the variables `{{index}}` & `{{value}}` in the `{{#each}}` context.

```js
Template.registerHelper('withIndex', function (array) {
  return _.map(array, function (val, i) {
    return {
      'index': i,
      'value': val
    };
  });
});
```

BTW, the `{{@index}}` context as per Handlebars/Spacebars specification should be in a new Meteor release soon, according to [this issue tracker](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/3560).

Comment: Looks like it was merged.