# Get item/element position in list using Meteor

Tags: meteor

How can you get an item's position in a list?

I'm trying to do something like the following:

Template:

```
{{#each people}}
  {{position}}.- {{name}}
{{/each}
```

JS:

```
Template.leaderboard.people = -> Players.find({}, { sort: { rank: 1 } })
Template.leaderboard.position = -> ???
```

So that if the data on Players is:

```
[ 
  { name: "Tom", rank: 1.2 }, 
  { name: "Dick", rank: 0.7 },
  { name: "Harry", rank: 1.5 }
]
```

The results will be:

```
1.- Dick
2.- Tom
3.- Harry
```

Maybe there's a way to do it with a mongo projection but I can't find how.

**Update/Answer:**

```
Template.leaderboard.people = -> 
  Players.find({}, { sort: { rank: 1 } }).map (doc,index) ->
    doc.position = index + 1
    doc
```

Comment: sounds like you'd want to write your own block helper (think `eachWithPosition`)

Comment: here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329898/is-there-a-way-to-get-index-while-iterating-through-collection-in-meteor

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler, and leverages the HTML tag for ordered lists:

```
<ol>
   {{#each people}}
      <li>- {{name}}</li>
   {{/each}
</ol>

Template.leaderboard.people = -> 
    Players.find({}, { sort: { rank: 1 } })
```

More details on 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp

And

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists